# pandas lookup value in column containing Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, lookup, intervals

I am trying to map a column of continuous float values to some discrete (bucketed) values based on the range into which the continuous value falls

e.g.

```
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.0, 0.3, 10.1],
                               [0.3, 0.65, 30.3],
                               [0.65, 1.0, 50.5]], 
                        columns=['start', 'end', 'mapped_value'])
# create intervals
df_lookup['interval'] = df_lookup.apply(lambda x: 
                                             pd.Interval(x['start'], 
                                                         x['end'], 
                                                         closed='both' if x['end']==1.0 else 'left'), axis=1)

df_lookup
```

Output:

|  | start | end | mapped_value | interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.00 | 0.30 | 10.1 | [0.0, 0.3) |
| 1 | 0.30 | 0.65 | 30.3 | [0.3, 0.65) |
| 2 | 0.65 | 1.00 | 50.5 | [0.65, 1.0] |

```
df_data=pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 0.3],
                           ['B', 0.65],
                           ['C', 0.6],
                           ['D', 0.75],
                           ['E', 0.4]], 
                     columns=['ID', 'original_value'])
df_data
```

|  | ID | original_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 0.30 |
| 1 | B | 0.65 |
| 2 | C | 0.60 |
| 3 | D | 0.75 |
| 4 | E | 0.40 |

At this point I use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to get my lookup value but

```
df_data['mapped_value'] = df_data.apply(
        lambda x: df_lookup.loc[x['original_value'] in df_lookup['interval']]['mapped_value'], 
            axis=1)
```

But this blows up telling me `KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'`

Further investigation shows me that the issue I have is that when I do the `in` I just get a single boolean value returned not a list of booleans, e.g., for data ID=`'A'` where the `original value` is 0.3, I am hoping that `x['original_value'] in df_lookup['interval']` would return `[False, True, False]` but in fact its returning `False`

I'd appreciate a little steer here on how to implement this "lookup" mapping. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with an optional check on the upper bound if the intervals are potentially disjoint:

```
df_data['mapped_value'] = (pd
 .merge_asof(df_data.sort_values(by='original_value'),
             df_lookup,
             left_on='original_value', right_on='start')
 # assign command below is only required if the intervals are disjoint
 .assign(mapped_value=lambda d: d['mapped_value']
                                .mask(d['end'].lt(d['original_value'])))
 ['mapped_value']
)
```

output:

```
  ID  original_value  mapped_value
0  A            0.30          30.3
1  B            0.65          30.3
2  C            0.60          30.3
3  D            0.75          50.5
4  E            0.40          50.5
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution with `Series.map`

There is no need to create an intermediate `interval` column instead you should create an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) which can be used to substitute the values in `df_data`

```
i = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_lookup.start, df_lookup.end, closed='left')
df_data['mapped_value'] = df_data['original_value'].map(df_lookup.set_index(i)['mapped_value'])
```

#### Result

```
print(df_data)

  ID  original_value  mapped_value
0  A            0.30          30.3
1  B            0.65          50.5
2  C            0.60          30.3
3  D            0.75          50.5
4  E            0.40          30.3
```

Comment: Hi Shubham - I dont think this accommodates the fact that the final interval is closed at both ends - can this approach be amended to incorporate that? I have played around a bit but get the error `ValueError: intervals must all be closed on the same side`

Comment: @JohnnieL i don't think you need closed interval on both sides because it doesn't makes sense  to having a single `mapped_value` as a part of multiple intervals.

Comment: Thats not the situatoin - input values are in the range 0<= x <= 1 and so the *final* interval needs to be bounded on both sides else I miss mapping data equal to the upper bound